# Live search React-Native + Meteor

Tags: search, meteor, react-native, live

I am wondering what is the best way to make a live search using Meteor and React-Native.

So we should do the search inside a MongoDB collection.

What is the best way? Subscribe everytime the text change? Subscribe once and get all the data and in local filter the data? ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the size of the collection to be searched.

- If it is very large, use a subscription with the search string as a parameter. However, *throttle* the searches so as to only search every 500ms or so. You typically don't need to search on every single character typed.
- If the collection is small, just subscribe to the whole thing and run the search on the client.

A variation of client-side search is that you just publish the field that you're going to search on then when the document is found you subscribe to a publication that gives you the rest of the fields for that one document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But when do I need to consider that my collection is big enough to have a sub with the searched "query"?

Comment: That's a judgment call but for me if it's going to take more than a half second to load. That would depend on the available bandwidth of course.